# this.state.users is an array, but still doesn't render in FlatList

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

So what I do now: I am using Firebase for my React Native project.
The user writes another user's email in . Then there is a check if this email exists in database. If the email exists, then it writes as an array to users=[] in state and should be rendered in FlatList.

Everything works fine except one thing: FlatList doesn't render anything though I have an array.

That's what I receive from console.log(users):

```
 [{...}]
  0:
    email: "test@gmail.com"
    id: "-LSVedv_anPyD3We-4_Q"
```

That's how my code looks like:

```
 state = {
  promptVisible: false,
  loading: false,
  users: []
 };

findUserEmail = (email) => {
 firebase.database()
 .ref(`/users`)
 .orderByChild("email")
 .equalTo(email)
 .once("value")
 .then(snapshot => {
  if (snapshot.val()) {
    const value = snapshot.val()
    this.setState({ users: Object.keys(value).map((id) => ({
      id,
      ...value[id]
    })), promptVisible: false})
  } else {
    Alert.alert("Email doesn't exist")
  }
  })
 }

 renderItem({item}) {
  return (
 <View style = {styles.contactContainer}>
  <View style={styles.userRow}>
    <View style={styles.userImage}>
      <Avatar
        width={60}
        rounded
        source={{
          uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Matterhorn_from_Domhütte_-_2.jpg/1200px-Matterhorn_from_Domhütte_-_2.jpg"
        }}
      />
    </View>
     <View>
      <View style={styles.emailBackground}>
       <Text
         style = {styles.contact} >
         {item.email}
       </Text>
       </View>
       <Text
          style = {styles.message} >
          Da inne lauft öpis...
       </Text>
      </View>
     </View>
   </View>
 )
 }

 render() {
  console.log(this.state.users);
   if (this.state.loading) {
return (
  <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1}}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="dodgerblue" />
  </View>
)
    }
    return (
<View style={styles.container}>
 <Header
   centerComponent={{ text: 'Nachrichten', style: { color: '#FF0000', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' } }}
   outerContainerStyles={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}
   rightComponent={this.renderButton()}
 />
 <View style = {styles.contentContainer}>
  <FlatList
   data={this.state.users}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   keyExtractor={item => item.email}
   />
 </View>
  <Prompt
    title="Email eingeben"
    placeholder="Email"
    visible={this.state.promptVisible}
    onCancel={() => this.setState({promptVisible: false})}
    onSubmit={(email) => this.findUserEmail(email)} />
</View>
);
}
```

So the question is what do I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: what happens if you replace this.state.users with a static array that you built by hand?

Comment: What do you mean? I don’t understand.

Comment: create a static array and use that instead of using state, to troubleshoot

Comment: Where should I pass it then?

Comment: You'd pass it directly to FlatList's data prop. Give me a dump of the user's array if you're still confused and I'll make it crystal clear

Comment: Never done it before, so can you show me how it works please?

Comment: by give me a dump, I just mean do a `console.log(this.state.users)`, but I'm at a computer now so I'll try to provide an answer that's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an error. That was too simple and dumb in the same way.

I just deleted this component in render and everything worked fine.

```
  <View style = {styles.contentContainer}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this...

```
<FlatList
   data={this.state.users}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   keyExtractor={item => item.email}
   />
```

With a static, object-filled array in the shape of what you expect `this.state.users` to look like. Here's an example...

```
<FlatList
   data={[{id: "A", email: "testA@gmail.com"},{id: "B", email: "testB@gmail.com"}]}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   keyExtractor={item => item.email}
   />
```

This won't solve your problem, but it's what I was suggesting as a troubleshooting step.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, but I’ve already published an answer before. It was because of <View> and wrong StyleSheet.